# Prove that $a . g = g^{-1}.a$ and $g . a = a . g^{-1}$ hold for any group and any action defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Dummit and Foote page 129 claims that for arbitrary group actions that if we are given a left group action of $G$ on $A$ then the map $A \times G \to A$ defined by $a . g = g^{-1}.a$ a is a right group action. Conversely, given a right group action of $G $ on $A$ we can form a left group action by $g . a = a . g^{-1}$.

For the special cases like action by conjugation or action of $D_8$ on ${\{1,2,3,4}\}$ it is easy to check that both relations $a . g = g^{-1}.a$ and $g . a = a . g^{-1}$ hold. But that's not a general proof and after a while attempt I can't prove it generally. Please help!

Comment: Not following.  That's the definition of the associated left group action.  You need to prove that it is, in fact, a group action...but equality is just the definition.

Comment: @lulu, you mean that right action is formed from the left action once we defined $g \ . a$ and applied $g \ . a = a \ . g^{-1}$? And vice versa?

Comment: exactly. You still have to check that it's a group action but that's it.

Comment: @lulu, Alright! Thanks a lot :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be clearer when using different symbols for the tow *different* actions talked about (and also different from the multiplication symbol in $G$). Even though the very axioms of group action are specifically so that this distinction feels unnecessary, it may be more helpful for this reasoning:

Assume we have a left group action $G\times A\to A$, where the image of $(g,a)\in A\times G$ is written as $g\star a$. Then we can define a map $A\times G\to A$, where the image of $(a,g)$ is written as $a\bullet g$ by letting
$$a\bullet g:= g^{-1}\star a.$$
We verify that this is a right group action, for example
$$\begin{align}(a\bullet g)\bullet h&=h^{-1}\star(a\bullet g) \\&= h^{-1}\star(g^{-1}\star a) \\&=(h^{-1}\cdot g^{-1})\star a \\&= \bigl((g\cdot h)^{-1}\bigr)\star a\\&=a\bullet (g\cdot h)\end{align}$$